# 管理者権限で実行したBATから管理者権限を外したい。

Tags: powershell, batch-file

#### 目的

管理者権限で実行したBATファイルから、別の実行ファイルを管理者権限を付与せずに起動したい。

**Hoge.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
START Notepad
Exit
```

この『Hoge.bat』を管理者権限で実行すると、メモ帳にも管理者権限が付与されるので、それを止めさせたいです。PowerShellや外部ツールを用いても構わないのでご教授頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

RUNASのtrustlevelオプションに0x2000を指定したら、一般ユーザー権限でコマンドを実行できるようです。

`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 実行コマンド`

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
早速試してみたのですが、コマンドプロンプト自体は通常起動した時と似たように起動しますが、それで何かを起動した場合はすべて管理者権限が付与されてしまいました。
（`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 CMD` → `START CMD`）など。
試しに`PAUSE`と書いただけ`test.bat`を用意しそれを実行（`runas /trustlevel:0x20000 test.bat`）してみましたがやはり管理者権限は付与されたままでした。

Comment: @水瀬敦美 さん、この記事 [【バッチファイル】管理者権限が無い場合に付与して実行](https://qiita.com/YamEiR/items/7f2734510544090611db) の方法で更にサブのバッチファイル(コメントで言うところのtest.bat)で確認したところでは、管理者権限が制限されたユーザーとして起動されているようですが。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
記事を読ませていただきましたが、つまりは`start.bat`、`管理者権限で実行したいbat`、`管理者権限で実行したくないbat`の三つを用意しろということでしょうか。
理解が悪く、大変申し訳ないのですがもう少し詳細な説明を頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: @水瀬敦美 さん、`START Notepad`を`RUNAS /TRUSTLEVEL:0x20000 Notepad`に変えれば良いのでは？